# Git Workflow Advice for team of 4 and update release daily

Tags: git, github

We have a web application that we update and release almost daily.
We are working on team of 4 developers and Using Git as our version control system.

The problem we are face now is...... "We can not update release daily anymore"

- Developers commit their work (merge from their feature-xx branch) to development branch
- From development branch we publish to Test server for Test
- Feature a (from developer a) Test =OK , but Feature b (from developer b) Test=Failed

We don't know how to get Feature a to release from development to master without the commits from feature b in between.
so we can not release Feature a to live

AND we also can not update a little commit(s) change in development to production because in development branch contain feature a and b.

What we would like to have

(1) ability to update and release daily

(2) once their branch merge to development branch, they can continue to develop their branch to next version of their feature

(3) we have now one test server, publish from development branch (every feature are there in one place for test)

We are thinking about Multiple Repositories instead of one repository.
For example

- Main repository

  - master branch
  - development branch
- Feature-A repository ( fork from Main repository - development branch )

  - master branch
  - feature a version 1
- Feature-B repository ( fork from Main repository - development branch )

  - master branch
  - feature b version 1

But we are still in same problem, we still can not update to release to only specific feature (feature A test=OK, feature B test=failed )

Can anyone please advice what we should do, what process we are missing??

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Multiple options:

1. Don't push broken code to develop. Just push to the test server from feature branches. If you need a centralized branch for publishing to your test server, create a new branch test and merge all testable features to it.
2. Publish to your test server from develop as you already do. But when you want to publish to your website, push from master. And make sure to only merge working feature branches to master and not everything from develop.

Comment: Thank you very much. We will start using option 1